# mysql Update using text range

Tags: mysql, sql-update, range

I am missing something here, but I am not seeing it.. I have an update as below.

```
UPDATE table SET field = 2 WHERE field2 > $FINIR AND InvoiceNo < $LINIR
```

The two strings will always represent numbers such as 12345.001 12345.005

The page runs with no errors but no updates are applied. This is driving me nuts now, any help would be great.

Comment: What row are you expecting gets modified? What values does it have?

Comment: All the rows between 12345.001 and 005.. I've tried the BETWEEN as well with the same results.